# Logstash _grokparsefailure when parsing Nginx logs

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to parse nginx logs using Logstash, everything looks fine, excepting getting this `_grokparsefailure` tag with lines containing an Nginx $remote_user. When the $remote_user is '-'(the default value when no $remote_user specified), Logstash do the job, but with a real $remote_user like `user@gmail.com` it fails and put a `_grokparsefailure` tag:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2017:23:14:08 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 169 "http://training-hub.tn/trainer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux
>   x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87
>   Safari/537.36"

=====> Works fine

> 127.0.0.1 - jemlifathi@gmail.com [17/Feb/2017:23:14:07 +0100] "GET /trainer/templates/home.tmpl.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>   "http://training-hub.tn/trainer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87
>   Safari/537.36"

=====>`_grokparsefailure` tag and fail to parse log line

I am using this configuration file:

```
input {     
    file {      
        path => "/home/dev/node/training-hub/logs/access_log"       
        start_position => "beginning"       
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => 0
        type => "logs"  
    }
}

filter {    
    if[type] == "logs" {        
        mutate {            
             gsub => ["message", "::ffff:", ""]         
        }       
        grok {          
             match=> [
               "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}",
               "message" , "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"
             ]
             overwrite=> [ "message" ]
        }

        mutate {
          convert=> ["response", "integer"]
          convert=> ["bytes", "integer"]
          convert=> ["responsetime", "float"]
        }
        geoip {
          source => "clientip"
          target => "geoip"
          database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
          add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
          add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
        }
        mutate {
          convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
        }

        date {
          match=> [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
          remove_field=> [ "timestamp" ]
        }

        useragent {
          source=> "agent"
        }   
     } 
 }

output {    elasticsearch {         hosts => "localhost:9200"   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing the output with many values, I realized that Logstash fails to parse log lines containing such `$remote_user` because it's not a valid username(an email address) so I've added a `mutate gsub` filter to remove the @ and the rest of the mail address to have a valid `$remote_user`.

> gsub => ["message",
>   "@(?:(?:a-z0-9?.)+a-z0-9?|[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)])
>   [", " ["]

And now, it works fine